# Interface Insanity

Tags: tdd, inversion-of-control, interface

I'm drinking the coolade and loving it - interfaces, IoC, DI, TDD, etc. etc. Working out pretty well. But I'm finding I have to fight a tendency to make *everything* an interface! I have a factory which is an interface. Its methods return objects which could be interfaces (might make testing easier). Those objects are DI'ed interfaces to the services they need. What I'm finding is that keeping the interfaces in sync with the implementations is adding to the work - adding a method to a class means adding it to the class + the interface, mocks, etc.

Am I factoring the interfaces out too early? Are there best practices to know when something should return an interface vs. an object?

Comment: Okay, now everybody... switch computers and read each other's code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interfaces are useful when you want to mock an interaction between an object and one of its collaborators.  However there is less value in an interface for an object which has internal state.

For example, say I have a service which talks to a repository in order to extract some domain object in order to manipulate it in some way.

There is definite design value in extracting an interface from the repository.  My concrete implementation of the repository may well be strongly linked to NHibernate or ActiveRecord.  By linking my service to the interface I get a clean separation from this implementation detail.  It just so happens that I can also write super fast standalone unit tests for my service now that I can hand it a mock IRepository.

Considering the domain object which came back from the repository and which my service acts upon, there is less value.  When I write test for my service, I will want to use a real domain object and check its state. E.g. after the call to service.AddSomething() I want to check that something was added to the domain object.  I can test this by simple inspection of the state of the domain object.  When I test my domain object in isolation, I don't need interfaces as I am only going to perform operations on the object and quiz it on its internal state.  e.g. is it valid for my sheep to eat grass if it is sleeping?

In the first case, we are interested in **interaction** based testing.  Interfaces help because we want to intercept the calls passing between the object under test and its collaborators with mocks. In the second case we are interested in **state** based testing.  Interfaces don't help here. Try to be conscious of whether you are testing state or interactions and let that influence your interface or no interface decision.

Remember that (providing you have a copy of Resharper installed) it is extremely cheap to extract an interface later.  It is also cheap to delete the interface and revert to a simpler class hierarchy if you decide that you didn't need that interface after all.  My advice would be to start without interfaces and extract them on demand when you find that you want to mock the interaction.

When you bring IoC into the picture, then I would tend to extract more interfaces - but try to keep a lid on how many classes you shove into your IoC container.  In general, you want to keep these restricted to largely stateless service objects.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you're suffering a little from [BDUF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Design_Up_Front).

Take it easy with the coolade and let it flow naturally.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that while flexibility is a worthy objective, added flexibility with IoC and DI (which to some extent are requirements for TDD) also increases complexity. The only point of flexibility is to make changes downstream quicker, cheaper or better. Each IoC/DI point increases complexity, and thus contributes to making changes elsewhere more difficult.

This is actually where you need a Big Design Up Front to **some** extent: identify what areas are most likely to change (and/or need extensive unit testing), and plan for flexibility there. Refactor to eliminate flexibility where changes are unlikely.

Now, I'm not saying that you can guess where flexibility will be needed with any kind of accuracy. You'll be wrong. But it's likely that you'll get something right. Where you later find you don't need flexibility, it can be factored out in maintenance. Where you need it, it can be factored in when adding features.

Now, areas which may or may not change depends on your business problem and IT environment. Here are some recurring areas.

1. I'd always consider external
   interfaces where you integrate to
   other systems to be highly mutable.
2. Whatever code provides a back end to
   the user interface will need to support change in the UI. However, plan for changes in functionality primarily: don't go overboard and plan for different UI technologies (such as supporting both a smart client and a web application – usage patterns will differ too much).
3. On the other hand, coding for
   portability to different databases
   and platforms is **usually** a waste
   of time at least in corporate
   environments. Ask around and check
   what plans may exist to replace or
   upgrade technologies within the
   likely lifespan of your software.
4. Changes to data content and formats are a tricky
   business: while data will
   occasionally change, most designs
   I've seen handle such changes
   poorly, and thus you get concrete
   entity classes used directly.

But only you can make the judgement of what might or should not change.

Answer (score 5):

I usually find that I want interfaces for "services" - whereas types which are primarily about "data" can be concrete classes. For instance, I'd have an `Authenticator` interface, but a `Contact` class. Of course, it's not always that clear-cut, but it's an initial rule of thumb.

I do feel your pain though - it's a little bit like going back to the dark days of .h and .c files...

Answer (score 2):

I think the most important "agile" principle is YAGNI ("You Ain't Gonna Need It"). In other words, don't write extra code until it's actually needed, because if you write it in advance the requirements and constraints may well have changed when(if!) you finally do need it.

Interfaces, dependency injections, etc. - all this stuff adds complexity to your code, making it harder to understand and change. My rule of thumb is to keep things as simple as possible (but no simpler) and to not add complexity unless it gains me more than enough to offset the burden it imposes.

So if you are actually testing and having a mock object would be very useful then by all means define an interface that both your mock and real classes implement. But don't create a bunch of interfaces on the purely hypothetical grounds that it might be useful at some point, or that it is "correct" OO design.

Comment: Please expound on the statement "all this stuff adds complexity to your code, making it harder to understand and change". It is core to the point in your answer but gives no reason as to *why* it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces have the purpose of establishing a contract and are particularly useful when you want to change the class performing a task on the fly. If there is no need to change the classes an interface just might get in the way.

There are automatic tools to extract the interface, so maybe you'd better delay the interface extraction later in the process.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on what you are providing... if you are working on internal things then the advice of "don't do them until needed" is reasonable.  If, however, you are making an API that is to be consumed by other developers then changing things around to interfaces at a later date can be annoying.

A good rule of thumb is to make interfaces out of anything that needs to be subclasses.  This is not an "always make an interface in that case" sort of thing, you still need to think about it.

So, the short answer is (and this works with both internal things and providing an API) is that if you anticipate more than one implementation is going to be needed then make it an interface.

Somethings that generally would not be interfaces would be classes that only hold data, like say a Location class that deals with x and y.  THe odds of there being another implementation of that is slim.

Answer (score -1):

Do not create the interfaces first - you ain't gonna need them. You cannot guess for which classes you'll need an interface of for which classes you don't. Therefore do not spend any time to burden the code with useless interface now.

But extract them when you feel the urge to do so - when you see the need of an interface - at the refactoring step.

[Those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class) can help too.