# Use attribute value of parent groovy script

Tags: oop, groovy, p-lang

I have some Groovy scripts which all have a ConfJava static attribute. A script can call another. So any script could be a parent or a child script.

If the script is called as a child script, I want them to use the last value in the config of the parent script. If it is called as the parent, I want them to use the value given by default in the static field. Here is two examples:

```
//procedure1.groovy
package procedureUtils.test

import groovy.transform.Field
import procedureUtils.config.Conf1

@Field static ConfJava config = new Conf1() // config.mode = "1"

exec()

static exec() {
    println "Procedure1 " + config.getMode()
    Procedure2.exec()
}
```

```
//procedure2.groovy
package procedureUtils.test

import groovy.transform.Field
import procedureUtils.config.Conf2
import procedureUtils.config.Conf3
import procedureUtils.config.ConfJava

@Field static ConfJava config = new Conf2() // config.mode = "2"

exec()

static exec() {
    println "Procedure2 " + config.getMode()
    config = new Conf3()
    println "Procedure2 after " + config.getMode()
    Procedure3.exec()
}
```

The important point is that ConfJava can be extended to create other custom Configuration classes based on ConfJava. Also, I can't pass the config in the exec() arguments (this is a constraint) nor change the static context in the groovy procedures files.

If I take the examples above, if Procedure2 is called by Procedure1, the output should be :

```
Procedure1 1
Procedure2 1
Procedure2 after 3
// and Conf3.mode value should propagate to Procedure3 etc. because it is the last state wanted by the developer in the exec() function
```

If I call directly Procedure2 as the parent, it should be:

```
Procedure2 2
Procedure2 after 3
// and Conf3.mode value should propagate to Procedure3 etc. because it is the last state wanted by the developer in the exec() function
```

The weird thing is, if I put `@Field static ConfJava config = new ConfJava()` in each files, except for one (lets say the second one) it correctly takes the parent script configuration (the ConfJava mode = "abs"). But if I change the `ConfJava` by `Conf1`, mode will equals "1" instead of the parent mode value.

Why does it only work correctly with the ConfJava class?
What can I do to respect all the constraints and solve my problem?

P.S.: I tried the option 4 of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549825/singleton-with-subclassing-in-java)

Edit :

#### How to run

Here is my file structure :
[image]

Here my configurations classes (ConfAbs and ConfDef are in Java, the others are groovy classes)

```java
// ConfAbs.java
package procedureUtils.config;


public abstract class ConfAbs {
  private static String mode = "abs";
  
  public static String getMode() {
    return mode;
  }

  public static void setMode(String newMode) {
    mode = newMode;
  }
}

// ConfDef.java
package procedureUtils.config;

public class ConfDef extends ConfAbs {

  public ConfDef() {
    setMode("Def");
  }
}
```

All the (except the abstract) have the same implementation for now, only the number changes

```
// Conf1.groovy
package procedureUtils.config

class Conf1 extends ConfAbs {
    Conf1() {
        setMode("1")
    }
}

// same for Conf2, etc.
```

Run the file Procedure1 above with IntelliJ or a groovy compiler (I do it with IntelliJ)
, right click -> run Procedure1.groovy)

Comment: do you have a _simple_ example that can be run?  Along with instructions on how to run it to see the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

you tagged your question with `OOP` when using static methods and fields is too far from `OOP`.

---

just pass your config as a parameter:

**P1.groovy**

```js
static exec(config){
    println "P1 conf=${config}"
    P2.exec(config)
}
exec("111")
```

**P2.groovy**

```js
static exec(config){
    println "P2 conf=${config}"
}
exec("222")
```

`groovy P1` command line will print:

```
P1 conf=111
P2 conf=111
```

`groovy P2` will print:

```
P2 conf=222
```

---

option 2 - declare config variable just once and use it from all scripts

**Global.config**

```
static @groovy.transform.Field config
```

**P1.groovy**

```
static exec(){
    println "P1 conf=${Global.config}"
    P2.exec()
}

Global.config = "111"
exec()
```

**P2.groovy**

```
static exec(){
    println "P2 conf=${Global.config}"
}

Global.config = "222"
exec()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but I have to not pass the config as a parameter.

Comment: then you have to rid of the static approach. or make one config for all instead of declaring it in each script - i have updated response with this option.