# AS3 - when to implement or extend?

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns

Take for example a multiple choice question game.

You have a MathQuestion and WordQuestion classes, should these implement an IQuestion interface, that defines say a question, answer, and difficulty functions OR is it more usual to extend a question base class, and override these functions?

Which is the more correct way of doing such things?

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way of thinking about the problem - is there actually any different between a MathQuestion and a WordQuestion?  To me, it sounds like they are both Question objects and you could differentiate between the different types via [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

You could start by defining an [Enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) class which lists the different types of Questions which appear in your Quiz (strictly speaking ActionScript 3 does not have proper Enums, but we can still achieve type safety with the following code.)

```
public class QuestionType {
    public static const MATH : QuestionType = new QuestionType("math");
    public static const WORLD : QuestionType = new QuestionType("world");

    private var _name : String;

    // Private constructor, do no instantiate new instances.
    public function QuestionType(name : String) {
        _name = name;
    }

    public function toString() : String {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

You can then pass one of the QuestionType constants to the Question Class when you construct it:

```
public class Question {
    private var _message : String /* Which country is Paris the capital of? */
    private var _answers : Vector.<Answer>; /* List of possible Answer objects */
    private var _correctAnswer : Answer; /* The expected Answer */
    private var _type : QuestionType; /* What type of question is this? */

    public function Question(message : String, 
                              answers : Vector.<Answer>, 
                              correctAnswer : Answer, 
                              type : QuestionType) {
        _message = message;
        _answers = answers.concat(); // defensive copy to avoid modification.
        _correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        _type = type;
    }

    public function getType() : QuestionType {
        return _type;
    }
}
```

Finally, a client (the code which makes use of the Question object) can query the question type easily:

```
public class QuizView extends Sprite {
    public function displayQuestion(question : Question) : void {
        // Change the background to reflect the QuestionType.
        switch(question.type) {
            case QuestionType.WORLD:
                _backgroundClip.gotoAndStop("world_background");
                break;

            case QuestionType.MATH:
                _backgroundClip.gotoAndStop("math_background");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks some great advice there. Although I do think for what I have in mind the question objects would be quite different, Math would generate various calculations whereas Word would query a DB.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on the exact specifics of your classes. If the classes functionality is radically different but share function/property names then an interface would be more appropriate. If the classes share a lot of common implementation, then it would be more appropriate to subclass.

From your description, the two classes seem to fit more into the category of "same function/properties" with different implementations and would probably be better off with an interface.

I generally use interfaces are too enforce a common behavior that a group of classes share whereas sub-classing is more appropriately used in cases where you can achieve serious code re-use through inherited functions/properties. At the end of the day it's mostly a design choice.

Comment: Right that was what I was thinking, the classes both need questions and answers, but the Math class would be generating calculations whereas the Word class would be querying a DB.