# variable return type in c++ class

Tags: c++, class

i have a class with the following structure:

```
class myClass
{
    private:
        int type;
        classOne objectOne;
        classTwo objectTwo;
    public:
        myClass(classOne object)
        {
            this->objectOne = object;
            this->type = 0;
        }
        myClass(classTwo object)
        {
            this->objectTwo = object;
            this->type = 1;
        }
}
```

i now want a method returning an object of type `classOne` if type is 0 and of type `classTwo` if type is 1. I do not want two methods to achieve this. the classes have different structures.

Is this even possible? Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: do `classOne` and `classTwo` share a common base class?

Comment: no, there are of completely different structure, i will add this to the question

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I will take the easy way and implement two methods and check for the type manually. i thought it could be simpler just having one method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html) to do this. A variant can be constructed directly from any value convertible to one of its bounded types. Similarly, a variant can be assigned any value convertible to one of its bounded types. Heres how you could use it in your class:

```
class myClass
{
    private:
        boost::variant<classOne, classTwo> obj;
    public:
        myClass(classOne object) : obj(object)
        {
        }
        myClass(classTwo object) : obj(object)
        {
        }
};
```

It also provides a very convenient `boost::get` to retrieve the value from the variant. 
You can use that to supply code for each bounded type you have(ie `classOne` and `classTwo`). Here is an example:

```
if (classOne * x = boost::get<classOne>(&obj))
{
    //Code for classOne
}
else if (classTwo * x = boost::get<classTwo>(&obj)
{
    //Code for classTwo
}
```

However, such code is quite brittle, and without careful attention will likely lead to the introduction of subtle logical errors detectable only at runtime. Thus, real-world use of variant typically demands an access mechanism more robust than `get`. For this reason, variant supports compile-time checked visitation via `apply_visitor`. Visitation requires that the programmer explicitly handle (or ignore) each bounded type. Failure to do so results in a compile-time error.

Visitation of a variant requires a visitor object. Like this:

```
class object_visitor
: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:

    void operator()(classOne & x) const
    {
        //Code for classOne
    }

    void operator()(classTwo & x) const
    {
        //Code for classTwo
    }

};
```

With the implementation of the above visitor, we can then apply it to `obj`, as seen in the following:

```
boost::apply_visitor( object_visitor(), obj );
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless the two types are related (in which case you can create a function that will return a pointer/reference to the common ancestor) you cannot do that directly in C++.

C++ is a statically typed language, meaning that the type of every expression must be known at compile time, but you are trying to define a function whose return type depends on runtime values.

Depending on the particular problem to solve, there might be different approaches that you could take, including using type erasure (return a `boost::any`, `boost::variant` or your own *type-erasure*).

Comment: `boost::variant` isn't really type-erasure, it's just a type-safe union.

Comment: @Xeo: You are right there. I misused the term. At any rate, you need to convert the system to have a unique return type, whether it is a typesafe union, or a type erased object is a detail.

Answer (score 1):

ClassOne and ClassTwo need to have the same return type then either via inheritance or composition.  i.e ClassOne and ClassTwo need to be subclasses of the same super class OR they need to impl the same interface.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the difference between implementing the same interface and inheriting from a base class?

Comment: Not that I want to spark the debate 1 versus the other in which is better--but (imo), composition allows for far more code reuse-ability, maintainability, and allows your solution scale for expansion.

Comment: Hint: in C++ there's no such thing as an interface - that's a Javaism

Comment: It can be mimicked with all virtual methods.  But that has nothing to do with the question you asked.

Comment: @awoodland: That C++ doesn't have a feature called "interface" doesn't mean it doesn't have interfaces. (There's abstract base classes with only virtual functions, after all.) Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56912/140719) for what an interface is vs a base class. (I'm sure there used to be an even better answer, but I can't find it.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would not use templates for your case.

You can have something like below:

```
template <class ClassType>
class myClass
{
    private:
        int type;
        ClassType object;            
    public:
        myClass(ClassType object_in)
        {
            this->object = object_in;
            /*
                C++ doesn't support reflection so I don't think there 
                is a robust way of doing the following at runtime.
            */
            type = /* Get Type at runtime */;
        }
        /*
            Have another method which return object in a straigtforward way.
        */
};
```

However, then this become trivial. Any more insight into what your use case is, such that you have to know the type?

**Update:**
If the ClassType is going to be an Object, you can have a `const static int TypeID` member for the class, which is set at compile time. You can then use it determine the Type at runtime.

Comment: I believe que question author wants a runtime behaviour, that is, the code called at runtime will either be for classOne, or classTwo. And C++ templates are resolved at compile time, so they can't help for this case.

Comment: Yeah. Hence to achieve a similar behaviour, I mentioned that the TypeID would need to be set at compile time in in advance for all the non native-types being used.

Answer (score 0):

If they're completely different structures, with no common base then an alternative way you can return them from the same function is to use `void*`.

**However** that's bad form in C++, usually indicating a design failure - either use two different functions, or use a common base class.

It's apples and oranges. If you put an apple into an recipe that calls for an orange it won't be the same recipe anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The use of type-id is a sign that you need virtual functions for myClass. Even if the other two classes are totally independent, the fact that they are returned by the same function could easily make them inherit a base class. And also you can just return a pair containing class1, class2 and one of them can be null.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is how you will determine the class of which type has been returned. I think it is possible to return a pointer to structure of this type

```
struct res {
  myClass* c1;
  ClassOne* c2;
} ;
```

The field of the not chosen class is NULL, the other points to the object.