# Variable return type

Tags: c++, boost, variable-assignment

Suppose you have something like the following:

```
class Shape  // base class
{
private:
    bool degenerate, ill_defined;
    ...
public:
    bool isVoid  () { return false; }
    bool isCircle() { return false; }
    bool isPoint () { return false; }
    bool isPlane () { return false; }
    bool isSphere() { return false; }
    ...
};

class Void : public Shape {
    ...
}

class Plane : public Shape
{
public:
    bool isPlane() { return !degenerate && !ill_defined; }
    bool isVoid () { return ill_defined; }
    ...
    operator Void () throw() { 
        if (isVoid()) return Void(); 
        else throw ...; //some error
    }
    ...
}

class Point : public Shape {
private:
    double radius;
    ...
public:
    bool isPoint() { return !ill_defined; }
    bool isVoid () { return ill_defined; }
    ...        
    operator Void () throw() { ... }
    ...
}

class Circle : public Shape // similar to the rest

class Sphere : public Shape // similar to the rest
```

The intersection between a `Plane` and a `Sphere` can be either

- a `Circle` (if the plane "cuts through" the sphere)
- a `Point`  (if the plane "just touches" the sphere)
- a `Void`   (if the sphere lies entirely above or below the plane)

I was wondering how to best define and use an intersection between a `Plane` and a `Sphere`, since the return type of the hypothetical

```
intersect(const Sphere& S, const Plane& P)
```

method/free function is unknown at compile time.

I never encountered this situation before, so I looked up some possible ways to do it. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234789/variable-return-type-in-c-class) which recommends `boost::variant`. In my situation, that would look like

```
boost::variant<Void, Point, Circle> intersection = 
    intersect(const Sphere& S, const Plane& P);
```

But this has three drawbacks:

1. It's fugly.
2. something like `intersection.radius` cannot be used as-is, since `Point` and `Void` do not have a `radius`. You'd have to do something like

   ```
   if (intersection.isPoint()){
       ...
   }
   else if (intersection.isCircle())
   {
       // possibly cast to Point if degenerate, otherwise:
       double R = intersection.radius;
       ...
   }
   // etc.
   ```
3. The user of a library implementing all these shapes would always have to know what types *could* be returned by intersecting two shapes. That is, the user would always have to declare something of type `boost::variant<scope::Void, scope::Point, scope::Circle>` which is complicated and just plain ugly. Fortunately, c++11 has the `auto` keyword for that. Alternatively, you could use a member like so

   ```
   class Sphere : public Shape
   {
       ...
   public: 

       boost::variant<scope::Void, scope::Point, scope::Circle>
           intersect_type;

       intersect_type intersect(const Plane& P);

       ...
   };
   ```

   so that we can use

   ```
   Sphere::intersect_type t = S.intersect(P);
   ```

   where `S` is an instance of `Sphere` and `P` an instance of `Plane`. But then still we'd have to have separate handling of all possible types:

   ```
   if (intersection.isPoint()){
       ...
   }
   else if (intersection.isCircle()){
       intersection.radius;
   }
   // etc.
   ```

so that the complexity we tried to take away from the user is actually still there.

I feel like I'm missing something here. Perhaps there is a smarter way to implement my `Shape` baseclass? Or should I create a separate, dedicated `Intersect` class? What solution is most elegant, efficient and effective for this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the question completely. The function `intersect` doesn't know the concrete class it is going to return until runtime. Then how can callers bind to a concrete type at compile time? They have to bind to a pointer to base class, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off-hand:

The `isXXXX()` predicate methods seem like a code smell to me. You'd do

- `if (dynamic_cast<Circle*>(shapePtr))` with RTTI usually
- Or use `variant::which()` and/or `variant::type()` to discriminate the variant's stored value

#### To your question:

There are several possible approaches.

1. The classic OO approach would be to just derive everything from Shape and always return a `std::unique_ptr<Shape>` (or similar).
2. However, obviously, you can do modern C++ *static* OO, in which case you'd end up with something similar to the variant. You'd then write a visitor to handle different cases:

<sup>(live on **http://liveworkspace.org/code/bad329cb40d94a21531e1153f4c0877b**)</sup>

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp>

struct Shape 
{ 
    /*virtual*/ double getSurface() const { return 42.0; }  // TODO
};

struct Circle : Shape {};
struct Point : Shape {};
struct Rect : Shape {};

struct Nil {};

typedef boost::variant<Nil, Circle, Point, Rect> Intersect;

struct DescribeVisitor : boost::static_visitor<std::string>
{
    std::string operator()(Circle const& s) const {
        return std::string("Got a circle of ") + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(s.getSurface());
    }

    std::string operator()(Rect const& s) const {
        return std::string("Got a rectangle of ") + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(s.getSurface());
    }

    std::string operator()(Point const& s) const {
        return std::string("Got a point of ") + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(s.getSurface()); // mmm bit funny :)
    }

    std::string operator()(Nil const&) const {
        return std::string("Got an empty intersection");
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Intersect const& i)
{
    return os << boost::apply_visitor(DescribeVisitor(), i);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Intersect describe = Point();
    std::cout << describe << std::endl;

    describe = Rect();
    std::cout << describe << std::endl;

    describe = Circle();
    std::cout << describe << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Got a point of 42
Got a rectangle of 42
Got a circle of 42
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you could:

1) Create overloaded operators/functions that return void *, which in turn would be linked to a member variable that holds it's true return value, as well as another member function with it's type.

2) Use a template, though that could be more trouble than it's worth.

3) Continue on with the boost::variant, and with the use of (but not death to) macro's clean it up some.

Granted, I'm mostly used to the C++98 still, ergo auto is just something I'm starting to play with. It may offer solace in the return as well, since it's determined at runtime I believe.

Comment: Could you give a small example of your first suggestion?

Comment: Judging by how the question sounds:


[code]//In class shape member variables
void *rVal;
int type; // 0 for point, 1 for circle, 2 for void, etc.
void *intersect(const Sphere& S, const Plane& P)
{
     //Do as needed
     if(isPoint) // If it's a point intersection
   {
     rVal = (void*)new Point; //Might be moot to cast to void *, but I'm a big fan of same type; old habits die hard
     type = 0;
   }

    //Other stuff here
   return rVal;
   }[/code]

Comment: Though, seeing the reply's I didn't even think of sehe's response, which is a great option as well.

Comment: I see, sort of the C way of doing it. Effective, but as @sehe indicated, smelly. I'm gonna go for his option. Thanks for thinking with me!

Answer (score 1):

If interaction with your shape types strictly depends on specific type and could not be reduced to some unified base interface that can be used in polymorphic way then the only thing that could help you to manage complexity is some form of [`Visitor`](http://www.swe.uni-linz.ac.at/research/deco/designPatterns/visitor/visitor.defaultroles.c++.html) pattern. You could make it intruisive with your class hierarchy, but [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/variant/) already has useful support for it - [`boost::static_visitor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#variant.concepts.static-visitor):

```
// Define processing for intersection types
struct IntersectionProcessor: boost::static_visitor<>
{
    void operator()(Sphere&)
    {
       // Process Sphere
    }

    void operator()(Point&)
    {
       // Process Point
    }

    void operator()(Void&)
    {
       // Process Void
    }

    template <typename T> void operator()(T&)
    {
       // Process any other shape
    }
};

// Usage
Sphere A;
Plane B;
auto intersectResult = intersect(A, B);
boost::apply_visitor(IntersectionProcessor(), intersectResult);

// Also easy to use as functor applied to container of results:
std::vector<intersect_type> intResVec = getIntersectionResults();
std::for_each(intResVec.begin(), intResVec.end(),
   boost::apply_visitor(IntersectionProcessor));
```