# How to have child classes return different value types from a virtual method

Tags: c++, json

I'm writing a sort of JSON parser.

So, I'm creating a class hierarchy for the different variable types that could be in there e.g. strings, ints, arrays, objects etc.

I figured it would be the easiest to have a virtual method `GetValue` which returns the value of the variable in the type that the variable would return.

So for example my `Int` type's `GetValue` method would return as an `int` and my `Array` type would return a `std::vector` or some such container via it's `GetValue`.

I'm unsure how to do this. I first thought that template arguments to a virtual method would work, but alas, they cannot be templated. I've gone via the route of virtual methods because I'm thinking that later on I would have some container of pointers to the base type, so my `GetValue` method would need to be virtual.

What is the way to return a `struct` that has the possibility of storing all types and relying on the caller to know which part of the struct to look for? Would it be a good idea to use a `class` that overloads the casting operators so it can return the correct piece of it's struct depending on where it's used?

Comment: From the approach you've begun, having the functions return [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) would work.

Comment: Imagine that you somehow managed to have such methods with different returns types - how do you plan to use them? What would the call site look like? How would you call `GetValue` on a base class pointer, and what would you do with its return value?

Comment: Have a look at [JsonBox](https://github.com/anhero/JsonBox)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234789/variable-return-type-in-c-class