# Advantage of using Interface over abstract class for repository pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface vs Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)

Its common to see the repository pattern implemented using Interfaces

```
public interface IFooRepository
{
   Foo GetFoo(int ID);
}

public class SQLFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
   // Call DB and get a foo
   public Foo GetFoo(int ID) {}
}

public class TestFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
   // Get foo from in-memory store for testing
   public Foo GetFoo(int ID) {}
}
```

But you could equally do this using abstract classes.

```
public abstract class FooRepositoryBase
{
    public abstract Foo GetFoo(int ID);
}

public class SQLFooRepository : FooRepositoryBase
{
    // Call DB and get a foo
    public override Foo GetFoo(int ID); {}
}

public class TestFooRepository : FooRepositoryBase
{
    // Get foo from in-memory store for testing
    public override Foo GetFoo(int ID); {}
}
```

**What are the specific advantages of using an Interface over an Abstract Class in a repository scenario?**

*(i.e. don't just tell me that you can implement multiple interfaces, I know this already - why would you do that in a repository implementation)*

**Edit to clarify** - pages like "[MSDN - Choosing Between Classes and Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229013.aspx)" can be paraphrased as "Choose classes over interfaces unless there is a good reason not to" - what are the good reasons in the **specific case of a Repository pattern**

Comment: Doesn't using an interface prevent boxing and the inefficiency this brings?

Comment: One being design choice.

Comment: @Pranay - where your answer go? :

Comment: @Ryan - that might not be useful so its better to remove it..

Comment: It's odd to use abstract classes for things that can be implemented with interfaces. http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/02/20/be-careful-mocking-concrete-or-abstract-classes/

Comment: He's saying that NMock or Rhino Mock don't handle abstract classes easily. If your framework (mocking/IoC/whatever) has limitations that favour one way over the other then thats part of the design decision, but it doesn't by itself make the other alternative 'Odd'

Comment: Isn't it the limitation of .net framework itself? P.S. As for the MSDN link, on SO the opposite opinion is more frequent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage of using an interface over an abstract class in this instance is that an interface is entirely transparent: This is more of an issue where you don't have access to the source of the class you're inheriting from.

However, this transparency allows you to produce unit tests of a known scope: If you test a class that accepts an interface as a parameter (using the dependency injection method), you know you're testing the class with a known quantity; the testing implementation of the interface will only contain your testing code.

Similarly, when testing your repository, you know you're testing just your code in the repository. This helps to limit the number of possible variables/interactions in the test.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I tend to have an interface that holds the signature for the methods that are purely "business-related" for example `Foo GetFoo()`, `void DeleteFood(Foo foo)`, etc. I also have a generic abstract class that holds protected methods like `T Get()` or `void Delete(T obj)`.

I keep my methods protected in the abstract `Repository` class so that the outside world is not aware of the plumbery (`Repository` will look like `object`) but only of the business model via the interface.

On top of having the plumbery shared another advantage is that I have for example a `Delete` method (`protected`) available to any repository but it is not public so I am not forced to implement it on a repository where it has no business meaning to delete something from my data source.

```
public abstract class Repository<T>
{
    private IObjectSet objectSet;

    protected void Add(T obj)
    {
        this.objectSet.AddObject(obj);
    }

    protected void Delete(T obj)
    {
        this.objectSet.DeleteObject(obj);
    }

    protected IEnumerable<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return this.objectSet.Where(where);
    }
}

public interface IFooRepository
{
    void DeleteFoo(Foo foo);
    IEnumerable<Foo> GetItalianFoos();
}

public class FooRepository : Repository<Foo>, IFooRepository
{
    public void DeleteFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        this.Delete(foo);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetItalianFoos()
    {
        return this.Find(foo => foo.Country == "Italy");
    }
}
```

The advantage of using the abstract class over an interface for the plumbery is that my concrete repositories do not have to implement method they don't need (`Delete` or `Add` for example) but they are at their disposal if they need it. In the current context, there is no business reason for to some Foos so the method is not available on the interface.

The advantage of using an interface over an abstract class for the business model is that the interface provides the answers to how it make sense to manipulate `Foo` from a business side (does it make sense to Delete some foos? To create some? etc.). It's also easier to use this interface when Unit testing. The abstract `Repository` I use cannot be unit tested because it is usually tightly coupled with the database. It can only be tested in integration tested. Using an abstract class for the business purpose of my repositories would prevent me from using them in unit tests.

Comment: But why? implementation(plumbing) can be hidden using either method.

Comment: The plumbery is shared by all the repositories (using the same data source). So all the repositories inherit from the same abstract `Repository` class. The plumbery is written once. The interface serves a specific business purpose. It's implemented only the repository that handle this purpose. Usually you don't have 50 data sources but you may have 50 business purposes. It's my way of doing because I think it's handy and clean but like everything there are several ways of doing.

Comment: So if I understand you from your delete example is that your saying that you prefer abstract classes over interfaces for a repository?

Comment: No, I use both. The abstract class and the interface serve different purpose. The abstract class serve the technical purpose (the plumbery, ie. communication with the data source) and the interface serves the business purpose/meaning of the repository. Let me add a more concrete example to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a general question that applies to any class hierarchy, not just repositories. From a pure OO point of view, an interface and a pure abstract class are the same.

If your class is part of a public API, the primary advantage of using an abstract class is that you can add methods in the future with little risk of breaking existing implementations.

Some people also like to define an interface as "something that a class can do" and a base class as "what a class is", and therefore will only use interfaces for peripheral capabilities and always define the primary function (eg. repository) as a class. I'm not sure where I stand on this.

To answer your question, I don't think there is any advantage to using an interface when it defines the primary function of the class.

Answer (score 2):

While others may have more to add, from a purely practical point of view, most IoC frameworks work better with interface -> class mappings. You can have different visibilities on your interfaces & classes, whereas with inheritance, the visibilities must match.

If you're not using an IoC framework, from my point of view there is no difference. Providers are based on abstract base classes.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the key difference would be, that an abstract class can contain private properties & methods, wherein an Interface cannot, as it's only a simple contract.

The result being an interface is always "no shenanigans here - what you see is what you get" whilst an abstract base class may allow side effects.

Comment: Why would that be important for a repository, or anything for that matter. The idea of encapsulation is that it does something without you having to worry about how - if there are shenanigans going on then maybe its for a good reason and you shouldn't actually know or care about it (obv. cases when you do need to know - but thats a leaky abstraction)

Comment: Well, interfaces & abstract classes both solve a similar problem "Defining a common contract" - personally I prefer Interfaces, but only for the reason specified above, and perhaps becuase the definitions just look neater. It may be one of those things that's simply personal taste.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the implementation of Tim McCarthy's Repository Framework.
< http://dddpds.codeplex.com/ >

He uses interfaces like `IRepository<T>` for defining the contracts, but he also uses abstract classes like `RepositoryBase<T>` or his `SqlCeRepositoryBase < T >` that implements `IRepository<T>`. The abstract base class is code to eliminate a lot dublicate code. A type specific repository just have to inherit frome the abstract base class and needs to add the code for its purpose. Users of the API can just code against the interface by contract.

So you can combine both approaches to use the advantages of them.

Additionally, I think most IoC-Frameworks can handle abstract classes.

Answer (score 2):

Since the pattern originates in Domain Driven Design, here's a DDD answer :

The contract of a Repository is usually defined in the Domain layer. This allows objects in the Domain and Application layers to manipulate abstractions of Repositories without caring about their real implementation and the underlying storage details - in other words, to be persistence-ignorant. Besides, we often want specific behaviors to be included in the contracts of some repositories (in addition to your vanilla Add(), GetById(), etc.) so I prefer the `ISomeEntityRepository` form than just `IRepository<SomeEntity>` - we'll see why they need to be interfaces later.

The concrete implementations of Repositories, on the other hand, reside in the Infrastructure layer (or in the Tests module for test repositories). They implement the above repository contract but also have their own range of persistence-specific characteristics. For instance, if you're using NHibernate to persist your entities,  having a superclass to all the NHibernate repositories with the NHibernate session and other NHibernate-related generic plumbing in it could come in handy.

Since you can't inherit several classes, one of these 2 things that your final concrete Repository inherits has to be an interface.

It's more logical for the Domain layer contract to be an interface (`ISomeEntityRepository`) since it's a purely declarative abstraction and mustn't make any assumption about what underlying persistence mechanism will be used - i.e. it *mustn't implement* anything.

The persistence-specific one can be an abstract class (`NHibernateRepository` or `NHibernateRepository<T>` in the Infrastructure layer) which allows you to centralize there some behaviors that are common to the whole range of persistent-store-specific repositories that will exist.

This results in something like :

```
public class SomeEntityRepository : NHibernateRepository<SomeEntity>, ISomeEntityRepository 
{
  //...
}
```