# Is this candidate for abstract class

Tags: c#

let's say that I want to collect in one place all common properties and behaviors for all sports. I was thinking to use SportBase as abstract class for this purpose but I'm not sure. I'm trying to understand the differences between Abstract vs Interface usage on this example.

Every sport should have following properties

- DateTime Started;
- DateTime Ended;
- string Name;

What if I declare these properties like integers and later on I decide to use Game object as separated entity like Game StartGame. I do not see clearly which approach to use with high level of abstraction to reduce pain on later modification (this modification can have adding new properties, new behaviors, etc.)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface vs Base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an interface to provide a contract to code to.

```
public interface ISportsEvent
{
    DateTime Start { get; set; }
    DateTime End { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but that doesn't give you a reusable implementation

As a general rule you should prefer composition over inheritance.

So its often better to do something like this

```
public interface EventDetails
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class SportingEvent
{

    public EventDetails Details {get;set;}
}
```

now this is a bit rough but you can see what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 3):

if you only have properties and empty methods an interface might be your better choice. if you have some actual code then abstract class is your only option. also remember that you can inherit only one abstract class but implement multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

No, I wouldn't do that.  You'll end up creating an abstract [God class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), which has way to many responsabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would probably make it an abstract class, since not only will your sports share some fields, but they might share some logic too.

Interfaces aren't for seperating out duplicate code, but they're purely for polymorphism.

All an interface does is guarantee that your class will act a certain way.  If you plan on putting logic in your base class than you want an abstract class.