# PHP object inheritage from class constructor - the right way

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I need some guidance about an php object inheritage situation.
I have:
a configuration object like:

```
configuration{
    var driver = 'mysql'; // or 'mssql';
    var host = 'database_host';
    var user = 'database_user';
    var password = 'database_password';
    var name = 'database_name';
}
```

two database handler classes:

```
class mysql{
    public mysql(){} // connect
    public query(){} // set a query
    public result(){} // load result
}

class mssql{
    public mysql(){} // connect
    public query(){} // set a query
    public result(){} // load result
}
```

and some kind of class controller:

```
class database{
    public function __construct(){
        $configuration = new configuration;
        /*
         * now, depending on the value of the $configuration->driver
         * my database class must inherit methods from mysql or mssql class
         */
        switch( $configuration->driver ){
            case 'mysql':
                // database inherit mysql methods
            break;
            case 'mssql':
            // database inherit mssql methods
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

usage like:

```
$database = new database;
$database->query( 'select * from some_table' );
$result = $database->result();
```

so, when I use my **database** class methods, depending on **configuration** object, I actually use **mysql** or **mssql** methods.
the way i see it is not passible because I want my **database** class to inherit another class in the class **constructor**.

I was hoping that someone could give me an advice about how can I do this.. let's say.. the right way.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing any inheritance here - is it `database` that should be extending something?

Comment: You seem to be talking about a 'factory' pattern. Look it up, it may assist to answer your question

Comment: for halfer question, I would like some kind of dinamically extend; the  thing is that i dont know what is the parent class until that 'switch' in the database contructor.

Comment: for thaJeztah, I will document about the factory pattern, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone, as confusend as me, reads this post, this is the solution I found (after weeks of research - yes, after weeks):

using singleton pattern, create a parent class called database:

```
class database{
    protected static $instances = array();

    // method to create a new instance of this object
    public function getInstance( $driver ){
        $instanceid = md5( $driver );

        if( self::$instances[ $instanceid ] == null ){
            self::$instances[ $instanceid ] = new $driver;
        }

        return self::$instances[ $instanceid ];
    }

    public function testFunction(){
        //do something else
    }
}
```

then create driver functions

```
class mysql extends database{
    public mysql(){} // connect
    public query(){} // set a query
    public result(){} // load result
}

class mssql extends database{
    public mysql(){} // connect
    public query(){} // set a query
    public result(){} // load result
}
```

now use it like

```
$database = database::getInstance( 'mysql' );
$database->query(); // works
$database->testFunction(); // works to
```

and further on you can use and like

```
$database = database::getInstance( 'mssql' );
$database->query(); // works
$database->testFunction(); // works to
```

**I need to apologize to Froncoise for unchecking his answer as the right one.**

Answer (score 1):

nonono, this is not oop-thinking. You should google the following keywords:

- prefer [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- [strategy pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy)
- [constructor injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/)
- prefer [interface over base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)
- [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle
- some kind of [factory pattern](http://corey.quickshiftconsulting.com/1/post/2009/5/first-post.html)

When you did, put the switch statement into the factory, make the class mysql an interface named *DBDriver*, and use the strategy pattern in your database class.

Comment: Thanks, i'll do some research. 
The thing is that, before posting this question I have read about 'interface', and I didn't quite get the use of it. 
I'll be back, after research :-)