# Android Java: best practice for common code in overrides for all Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, extend

I'm not entirely sure whether the following approach is a good or terrible one.
It would be great if someone more experienced could add his/her 2 cents :)

I have an app with lots of Activities.
In this case all of them must be able to receive messages from a dynamically registered receiver (in onCreate/Resume/Pause....) using LocalBroadcastManager and run an AsnycTask to do some work and display a ProgressDialog.
The code needed (Receiver and AsnycTask) is absolutely the same for all Activities.

The messages can be sent at any time by one of the services.

To do that I created an Activity which implements all that (registers and unregisters the receiver in oncreate/pause/resume et.c. and contains this AsyncTask)

All other Activities should extend this Activity so I don't need to worry about putting extra code into all of their respective onCreate/onResume/onPause methods to call any helper classes/methods (and forgetting to do so).

Is this approach ok?
I ask because I once stumbled upon a similar question about extending Activities from a custom class (regretfully I can't find it anymore) and one answer suggested that it would cause massive memory leaks without explaning why.

Thank you very much!

Comment: From the point of view of Java it is ok. Optional, make the base class abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a lot of success using a BaseActivity class that all other Activities in my project extend from.  I've yet to encounter any memory issues due to this.

An alternative approach would be putting your common functionality in Interfaces, then having your Activities implement these as necessary.  There's some really good discussion of the merits of these two approaches here: [Interface vs Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm relieved to hear that it's ok :) Yes I'm using both interfaces and a Base class.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my 2cents, I agree with MattDavis, I always set a "BaseActivity" which I find very useful.

there is nothing wrong with overriding onCreate, however there are some additional options.

1. In your BaseActivity, you can set a method before and after your "onCreate stuff" but still inside the onCreate method.  In mine, i use "PreUILoad()" and "PostUILoad".  Then I can override those methods to add anything before or after my default onCreate without possibly screwing up the onCreate.
2. An even better solution is to implement this library which makes things 100 Times easier.  I simply set up my "BaseForm" (Form extends activity) to have my items, and then everything else extends BaseForm.  In all other Forms, I don't even need to touch onCreate, just the "Define" method, which sets everything up, and I never have to worry about messing with onCreate.  Info is here:

https://code.google.com/p/alternate-java-bridge-library/

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks very much for the insight and also for the link. I'm sorry I can't flag both of your replies as answers so I chose the first one.