# multiple inheritance in c#.net - abstract classes

Tags: c#, .net

One quick question.

I understand that multiple inheritance is not supported in c#.net. But you can still achieve the functionality by implementing multiple interfaces. Now my question is Can a child class inherit from two or more classes as long as they are abstract?

Comment: Did you try it?  Should be pretty easy to find out (my hunch is that the answer is no, because an abstract class is still a class).

Comment: No, an abstract class is still a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can only inherit from one class whether it is abstract or concrete.

Here is link to a question that has quite a detailed discussion of abstract vs base classes

[Interface vs Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)

Answer (score 8):

In short, no. Multiple interface <strike>inheritance</strike> implementation is possible, but not multiple class inheritance (abstract or not).

Comment: You mean multiple interface implementation, not inheritance, right?

Comment: Yes, I meant implementation. Late tonight... and family party with a few too many brews ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't inherit from multiple classes, period. No matter if abstract or not. Read about extension methods, that may help you a bit: if your classes implement an interface, you can attach common functionality to them without inheritance and copy-paste.

Comment: What do extension methods have to do with interface implementation?

Comment: @Tim: Nothing, like I said, they may be used *instead* of inheriting from a base class.