# Difference between abstract Class and Interface in C#

Tags: c#, oop

this article says 
[Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838365/Basic-Csharp-OOP-Concept%20Interface-only%20method%20Declaration)
Abstract Class -can have method Declaration and  method definition.

But this article says
[programcall](http://programcall.com/27/csnet/abstract-classes-and-abstract-methods-in-csnet.aspx)
Abstract - can have only method Declaration.

I got confused. Can anybody clear me what is the exact difference of both ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class

Answer (score 3):

See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11155/Abstract-Class-versus-Interface):

> Multiple inheritance

A class may inherit several interfaces.

A class may inherit only one abstract class.

> Default implementation

An interface cannot provide any code, just the signature.

An abstract class can provide complete, default code and/or just the details that have to be overridden.

> Access Modfiers

An interface cannot have access modifiers for the subs, functions, properties etc everything is assumed as public   An abstract class can contain access modifiers for the subs, functions, properties
Core VS Peripheral

Interfaces are used to define the peripheral abilities of a class. In other words both Human and Vehicle can inherit from a IMovable interface.

An abstract class defines the core identity of a class and there it is used for objects of the same type.

> Homogeneity

If various implementations only share method signatures then it is better to use Interfaces.

If various implementations are of the same kind and use common behaviour or status then abstract class is better to use.

> Adding functionality (Versioning)

If we add a new method to an Interface then we have to track down all the implementations of the interface and define implementation for the new method.

If we add a new method to an abstract class then we have the option of providing default implementation and therefore all the existing code might work properly.

Fields and Constants    No fields can be defined in interfaces  An abstract class can have fields and constrants defined

Comment: A class doesn't inherit from an interface, it implements it.  There is no multiple inheritance in C#.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Yes exactly

Comment: Can abstract method have code definition  with in abstract Class? @Shahrooz

Comment: @King_Fisher No.But You can use virtual method and then overrdie it in sub  calss

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, abstract classes can already implement *some* methods or variable's values, as long as it does not implement them *all* (which would make it a normal class).
An interface cannot do this; it can only provide method and variable stubs.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is more of a contract - it details what methods or properties will be found on an object that implements it.

An abstract class is a base object - it can contain methods, variables and behaviour - however you cannot create a concrete implementation of it - you must inherit from it and extend its behaviour.

Comment: Not "can be found" - instead "**will** be found".