# When creating object from classes that extend other classes

Tags: java, inheritance

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
```

Just looking at some sample code where ServiceResultHandler extends the Handler class.

```
public class ServiceResultHandler extends Handler {
}
```

In other classes where this is used I have seen it been declared like this:

```
private Handler mServiceResultHandler;
```

and being instantiated like this:

```
mServiceResultHandler = new ServiceResultHandler();
```

My question is shouldn't mServiceResultHandler be a ServiceResultHandler instead of a Handler i.e?

```
private ServiceResultHandler mServiceResultHandler
```

Just seems odd to me to have the type as Handler when ServiceResultHandler inherits all the attributes of the Handler class anyway.

Comment: I am sorry I have read through this twice now and still don't fully understand your question, is it what `extends x` means or just why it is inherited?

Comment: The question is - If `Handler` were an interface, it makes sense to declare `Handler msrh = new MSRH();`, but currently, it is a parent class. **Does it make sense to declare a child class object as a parent class type?**

Comment: I think this kind of question has been asked before, here is a link to a post which can hopefully help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class

Comment: @PavanKumar Handler is just a public class.

Comment: @Fapprentice I can understand if Handler was an interface. But its just a normal class.