# Initialise several diferent classes that implement the same interface

Tags: java, class, oop

I've got several different classes that implement the interface as shown below:

```
public class Class1 implements interface1 {

    @Override
    public void action(){
        //do somethod
    }
}

public class Class2 implements interface1 {

    @Override
    public void action(){
        //do somethod
    }
}

public class Class3 implements interface1 {

    @Override
    public void action(){
        //do somethod
    }
}
```

My question is, then when I initialise those classes, how can I call the action method for each one of them in a loop. I was thinking of storing them in a list and then walk through it and call them, but I couldn't make it.

Comment: a List<interface1> should do the job

Comment: I was thinking if it's a good method of doing so, or it is better if I create a parent class?

Comment: it works so keep it simple and don't create a useless parent. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class?rq=1

Comment: @Avtontom_ creating a parent class wouldn't really make a difference in your simple example. Just using the first common parent which contains the methods you need will be the best solution.

Comment: Got it, thanks to both of you.

Comment: Do you want to implement the "Class" or do you want to create three objects and initialise the objects. I think you are confused by the difference between a class and an object. If you want to call action() when the object is created (initialised) just call it from the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have different classes that implements certain interface you may deal with them in polymorphic way.

First, lets change your code to make it according to java code conventions:

```
public interface Interface {

      void action();
} 

public class ClassOne implements Interface {

    @Override
    public void action(){
        System.out.println("class one action");
    }
}

public class ClassTwo implements Interface {

    @Override
    public void action(){
        System.out.println("class two action");
    }
}

public class ClassThree implements Interface {

    @Override
    public void action(){
        System.out.println("class three action");
    }
}
```

After that create list and add new instances to it and call method `action()` for each element in list, you don't need to know actually what class instances presents in list, you only need to know that all of them implements certain interface.

```
List<Interface> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ClassOne());
list.add(new ClassTwo());
list.add(new ClassThree());
for(Interface instance : list) {
    instance.action();
}
```

output will be:

```
class one action
class two action
class three action
```

P.S. you may even write this in one line with java 8/9

*java 8*

```
Arrays.asList(new ClassOne(), new ClassTwo(), new ClassThree()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

*java 9*

```
List.of(new ClassOne(), new ClassTwo(), new ClassThree()).forEach(System.out::println);
```